# Load drivers by changing USB Device VID and PID

Tags: usb, drivers, webcam, camera

My USB 2.0 Device is listed as PC Camera under the "Device description" of Device Manager. Its Hardware Ids are "USB\VID_0458&PID_2029&REV_0000&MI_00" and "USB\VID_0458&PID_2029&MI_00".

I believe it is a simple USB camera. However, the combination of VID and PID of the device prevents USB camera drivers from loading. Searching Google for the VID and PID does not yield any useful results.

I have tried looking at spoofing or modifying the VID and PID of the device to other common VIDs and PIDs of USB cameras, to no avail.

Ultimately, I would like to get this USB camera device working, which means that it acts as a webcam. The Windows 10 Camera app should be able to display whatever the USB Camera device is pointed at.

Answer (score 2):

To get your device recognized by universal OS drivers, it should expose the appropriate [device class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_classes) and support relevant protocols. If it is listed as the "Camera", it maybe exposes the video class (you can check it in Device Manager, opening device properties - Details - "Device Class") but does not support all mandatory protocols.

If you want to forcibly load a particular driver from a compatible camera, just copy INF file of the appropriate driver, and replace VID/PID/REV/MI with your device IDs. If this INF has a signed catalog file (CAT), you will need to manually disable driver signature enforcement in Windows boot menu, pressing F8 on early boot time.