# Change default driver for USB-device

Tags: windows, drivers, game-controller, hid, usb-hid

I'm working on a small project which uses PlayStation Buzz!-controllers. The newer controller get automatically detected has HID-devices, but the older versions are unfortunately detected as a malfunctioning USB-Hub. It is possible to manually install each device as a HID-device, but unfortunately, this manual configuration is lost after restart.

Is there a way to change the default driver for devices with a given vendor- and product ID?

Comment: I mean you could write your own .inf https://superuser.com/questions/1394090/load-drivers-by-changing-usb-device-vid-and-pid

Comment: Have to tried replacing the driver? If that doesn't work, you can technically grab the working drivers, copy over the device ID, and then replace the driver.

Comment: @Nelson, I don't think that works -- the drivers and inf files are signed and rejected if the text is modified. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831608/how-to-install-winusb-driver-through-customized-inf-file-on-windows-10